# hands with 13 cards from a shuffled pack of 52 cards

Tags: combinatorics

How many hands of 13 cards dealt from a normal shuffled pack of 52 cards contain exactly two kings and one ace?

#### try

We can choose ${52 \choose 13}$ such hands and since we want two kings, we must select 4 out of a suit so we count ${14 \choose 4}$ and one ace is ${4 \choose 1}$ since there are 4 suits only. Thus, in total we have

$$ {52 \choose 13}{14 \choose 4}{4 \choose 1} $$

is this correct?

Comment: You're picking $18$ cards out of $52+14+4$ here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please notice that ${N\choose{a}}$ is the number of groups you can get if you take $a$ objects from a set of $N$ distinct objects.

Hence, $52\choose13$ is the *total* number of different hands, of **all** hands. Thus $52\choose13$ is already bigger than the answer you are looking for. Combinatorics questions are better answered if broken in pieces:

To make a hand satisfying said restrictions you need:

- 10 cards that are not aces nor kings;
- 2 kings;
- 1 ace;

There's $4$ ways of picking an ace. There are $4$ kings in total, hence $4\choose2$ ways of picking those. From the $52$ cards in a deck, $44$ are not aces nor kings, thus you pick $10$ from those in $44\choose{10}$ different ways, amounting to a total of

$$4\cdot {4\choose{2}} \cdot {44\choose{10}}$$

different hands.

Answer (score 1):

You need $2$ kings out of the $4$, $1$ ace out of the $4$ and $10$ cards from the remaining $52-8 = 44$, so

$$\binom{4}{2} \binom{4}{1} \binom{44}{10}$$

in all. Divide by $\binom{52}{13}$ to get the probability for such a hand.